# API JSON using number

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

I'm working with Angular 4 and I have used the CoinMarketCap API. But there's a field that's been giving me a big headache. Any suggestions?

this:

```
"24h_volume_usd": "72855700.0",
```

this is my html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let coin of coins">
  <td>{{coin.24h_volume_usd | currency:'USD':true:'1.0-2'}}</td>
</tr>
```

this is error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
 Parser Error: Unexpected token '0.24' at column 5 in [{{coin.24h_volume_usd | currency:'USD':true:'1.0-2'}}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbols can't start with a number in JS.  So you'll need to use the array syntax:

```
<td>{{coin['24h_volume_usd'] | currency:'USD':true:'1.0-2'}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can't begin a property with a number. So change `24h_volume_usd` to something else such as `_24h_volume_usd`

I just tried modifying one of my variables to start with a number and also see several syntax errors.